# nginx valid_referer for all files inside a directory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have this config

```
location /mirror/files {
    valid_referers none server_names example.com *.example.com;
         if ($invalid_referer) {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/;
        }
    index index.php;
}
```

If I visit a link http://example.com/mirror/files/test.zip with referer that start with "http://example2.com" I can access the file.
How to make it work?
UPDATE: I can see from the server logs the referer is sent so it's not empty.

Answer (score 0):

OK the reason was that I was using a localhost referer (my local development env) and apparently nginx treats that if it's coming from the local server which is silly since the IP should be checked if it's local as well.

Solution is either use real domains as referers or set your local server with another severname than localhost.